# jquery draggable

Tags: jquery, draggable

i have a div i want to drag confined in a particular container. 
i tried using the containment: parent option but this results in the div getting snapped to upper or lower bounds without dragging. i have overflow:hidden set, i hope that is not a problem. (i read it somewhere)

pls help me out.

the code:

```
imgCanvas.appendChild(img); 
overlay.appendChild(imgContainer);

$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    containment: '#imgContainer', 
    scroll: false
  });                                                       
});
```

the #draggable is a div that contains the img, and #draggable is appended to imgContainer. i hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Show us some code and help will come running like a bat out of hell.

Comment: @karim79: LOL, so true though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works perfectly for me (You'll have to modify the containment plots to match your draggable element dimensions though):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <title>jQuery</title>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>

          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#draggable").draggable({
              containment: [-150,-150,0,0],
              scroll: 'false'
            });
          });

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
          #container {
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            border:1px solid #cccccc;
            overflow:hidden;
          }
          #draggable {
            width:359px;
            height:359px;
            background:#cc0000 url("http://www.sudoku.4thewww.com/Grids/grid.jpg");
          }
        </style>
      </head>
    <body>

      <div id="container">
        <div id="draggable"></div>
      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that does work. but the main point has not been included. i mentioned that i have the overflow:hidden CSS property set for the image to be dragged. the image is larger than the container.

Comment: amit - I've updated the code to include an image larger than the container, and used overflow:hidden on the container. The main difference is the containment value - you use a series of plots this time, [x1,y1,x2,y2].

Comment: works like a charm. but the right and bottom areas are still exposed. i mean to say the image continues to drag left and top to display the background on the right and bottom area of the div.

Comment: You need to modify the plots provided. Mine were for a different-sized image.

Comment: what if i have different images of different sizes? how do i cope with that?

Comment: You can likely work up a small equation using $(".selector").width() and $(".selector").height() to automatically determine those plots.

Comment: But then you need to redo that if the user does something like resize his browser window; the ideal solution would just to have the jQuery draggable obey the conainment parameter, even if its own contiainer if larger than that of the containment element.

Comment: Further to my last comment - if you set the container to scroll:auto and position:relative, then the draggable will cause the container to scroll when it hits the edge.  This might also be useful (it was exactly what I was after anyway).

Comment: this does what I'm after.  see the code running on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pK85a/

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this same problem. I extracted my code into a plugin which I think does exactly what you're after...

details here:

http://webpangea.blogspot.com/2009/10/draggable-scrolling-list-with-jquery.html